# Scala source external to SBT project folder

Tags: scala, sbt, intellij-14

When creating an SBT scala project in ItelliJ, it wants me to put all source code in the src/main/scala folder of the project folder. However, I want to put the source code somewhere else independent or particular projects, build-tools, IDEs, etc.

How do I tell it to get the source from arbitrary locations?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to put source for a project outside  non-standard location? Do you want to have multiple sub projects contained inside the same project? If so, then have a look at the directory structure of the [Akka](https://github.com/akka/akka) project on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, I understand how the current IDE's want you to organize things. Coming from other languages, it has just been my custom to keep general-purpose source code separate from project files, build outputs, IDE artifacts, etc. I don't view it as "source for a project". Source code lives conceptually in the space of the language, not in a particular project for a particular build tool or IDE, which come and go. "project" is not a concept in the scala language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following settings to change the location where *SBT* looks for your *Scala* sources:

```
// Change Scala source directory. Default is:
// scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "scala"
scalaSource in Compile := file("<Path to your sources...>")

// Change Scala test source directory. Default is:
// scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test" / "scala"
scalaSource in Test := file("<Path to your test sources...>")
```

For further information (including how to specify other source, library and resource directories), refer to the [official *SBT* documentation for customizing paths](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html).

Comment: @devx Hope you noted the update. I originally forgot that paths need to be specified as `File` instances (available through the _SBT_ `file()` function).